# Proof involving contour integrals

Tags: complex-analysis, contour-integration

Let $a$ be given and let $\gamma$ be a simple closed curve oriented counterclockwise. Suppose that $\gamma$ encloses the numbers $z=\pm ai$. Show that

$\int \frac{e^z}{z^2+a^2}dz = \frac{2\pi i\text{sin}a}{a}$.

Usually with these problems I can find a way to rewrite the integrand and apply Cauchy's theorem or the deformation theorem. I'm not sure how to begin here however.

Also:

Let $f$ be analytic "on and inside" a simple closed curve $\gamma$. Suppose that $f=0$ on $\gamma$. Show that $f=0$ inside $\gamma$.

My proof:

Let $z_0$ be inside $\gamma$. Then by CIF we have

$f(z_0) = \int_{\gamma} \frac{f(z)}{z-z_0}dz$. But since $f=0$ on $\gamma$, we have $f(z_0) = \int_{\gamma} \frac{f(z)}{z-z_0}dz = 0$. Since $z_0$ was an arbitrary point inside $\gamma$, $f=0$ inside $\gamma$.

Comment: It is a direct application of [residue theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Residue_theorem). (Have you heard of it?) What is left is to calculate residues at $\pm ai$ and add them.

Comment: I haven't learned about the residue theorem. Is there some other way to do it?

Comment: Then maybe partial fraction is the way to do it.

Comment: That's what I was thinking, but I wasn't sure how to decompose this fraction. Any advice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

\begin{align}
\oint_{\gamma} \frac{e^z}{z^2+a^2}\mathrm dz&=\oint_{\gamma} \frac{e^z}{(z-ia)(z+ia)}\mathrm dz\\
&=\frac {1}{2ia}\oint_{\gamma} \left (\frac{e^z}{z-ia}-\frac{e^z}{z+ia}\right)\mathrm dz\\
&=\frac {1}{2ia}(2\pi i e^{ia}-2\pi i e^{-ia})\\
&=2\pi i\frac {e^{ia}-e^{-ia}}{2i\,a}\\
&= \frac{2\pi i\sin a}{a}
\end{align}

Comment: Does this use the information that the closed curve contains the roots?

Comment: Would you mind explaining how you got from the 2nd line to the 3rd? Everything else makes sense to me.

Comment: [Cauchy's integral formula](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%27s_integral_formula).

Comment: I wasn't familiar with CIF before, but now I am after reading your link -- makes the problem very easy. Quick question about it: for the f(z) (numerator in the RHS of the formula) inside the integral, we are talking about the values of f(z) that are on the curve gamma, right? and the f(a) (LHS of the formula) is a point inside? Referring to your link for the notation.

Comment: $f (a) $ need not be inside the region enclosed by the path. But note that $a $ is inside the contour. In some sense, CIF allows one to calculate the image of an interior point just by using the behaviour of the function at the boundaries.

Comment: Okay. Thanks. I was asking because I'm working on a proof involving CIF. I'll edit it into my post. Would you mind taking a look?

Comment: Looks fine to me.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**:

$$\int_\gamma \dfrac{e^z}{z^2+a^2}\mathrm dz=\int_\gamma\dfrac{e^z}{(z-ia)(z+ia)}\mathrm dz=2\pi i (\text{Res}_{z=ia}+\text{Res}_{z=-ia})$$

---

$$\dfrac{e^z}{(z-ia)(z+ia)}=\dfrac{e^z}{2ia}\left[\dfrac{(z+ia)-(z-ia)}{(z+ia)(z-ia)}\right]=\dfrac{1}{2ia}\left[\dfrac{e^z}{z-ia}-\dfrac{e^z}{z+ia}\right]$$

Doing the Partial Fraction Decomposition you can use the Cauchy Integral Formula for Derivatives to solve this Contour Integral which is stated as follows:

$$f^{(k)}(w)=\dfrac{k!}{2\pi i}\oint \dfrac{f(z)}{(z-w)^{k+1}}\mathrm dz$$

Further make use of De Moivre's result which immediately gives you the result as $2\pi i \sin a /a$.

Comment: Shouldn't that last equality in the second line have a $2$ in the denominator?

Comment: @mXdX Yes it should, I corrected it. Thanks for pointing out.